# Selection and beveling

Tags: selection-tools, bevel

I selected six points, applied bevel, then applied extrude without removing the selection and made holes.

Then I want to bevel multiple holes, but I don't want the bevel applied to the inner edges. How can I remove edges from a set of holes?

[image]

Comment: Hello, is your question how to deselect certain edges?

Comment: Actually when I do that, only the edges at the bottom of the holes are selected... but anyway: you can select vertices, bevel them, extrude them, but don't know how to select the edges you want to bevel? Or do you ask for something else which I don't understand from your question?

Comment: Honestly don't know how you arrived at this with ngons on the extruded parts :p

Answer (score 1):

Flip to a side view and turn on *X-Ray* mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and you can box select only the extruded faces.  Here I'm in Vert select mode, keyboard shortcut <kbd>1</kbd>.

[image]

Since your faces are ngons the bevel comes out clean.

[image]

Be aware your model also has some stray edges here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you :), your method helped me with the X Ray mode. 

One more thing, when bevel is applied via modifiers (procedural) then the angle can be set there, and you can set it so that bevel does not trigger internal edges, but only those parts that need to be chamfered (rings)

I would like to achieve this effect when bevel is done with ctrl + b in edge mode, but there is no rotation angle function

Comment: Try giving a bevel weight to the edges and using weight mode on the modifier

Comment: @AllenSimpson How should giving a bevel weight achieve what is asked for in the comment... limit beveling in _Edit Mode_ to edges with certain angles?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann it doesn't satisfy that requirement perfectly, but it's a workaround to be able to designate those edges in edit mode but have procedural control over the bevel :) - I think bevel mod does have an angle limit setting, but I use bevel weight more, personally

Comment: @AllenSimpson Yes, of course the _Bevel_ modifier has an angle limit setting, that is explicitly mentioned in the comment - and also explicitly asked for how to do that without the modifier. So a workaround with the modifier is irrelevant.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann leave an answer if you're better able to understand what they want, personally when I see a question that says "I don't want X solution", I wonder if it's for Y reason ;)

Comment: @AllenSimpson I don't know what they want, that's what I said in the comment but since the OP doesn't bother to answer I'm not going to give any answer on this. I just know it was said "not the modifier". It might help if he explained why not the modifier to find an answer. It also appears as if he doesn't know how to select certain edges - so giving them bevel weights could be difficult, too.